# Data-driven dropdown menu Katalon Automation Recorder

Tags: selenium, ide, dropdown, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I'm trying to automate click with Selenium IDE. I was trying to figure out if I can use the "Select" command, but it didn't work.

I would like to click on the value on the dropdown that I put in my CSV file. Like I want a specific value of the dropdown for each line of my CS.

Here's the code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Don't do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361474/should-we-display-a-warning-when-users-include-images/361481#361481). Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

[Katalon [WebUI] Select](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/webui-select-option-by-value.html) is meant only to select [default html select](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) component. Yours is custom select box.

You need to select that exactly same way as you do manually like

- Click the menu
- Wait for dropdown to be visible
- Select the particular value based on name from your csv

Based on your html, your Katalon script will be like this,

```
TestObject menu = new TestObject('Menu').addProperty('css', ConditionType.EQUALS, "div.md-select-menu-container")
WebUI.click(menu)

TestObject dropdownValue = new TestObject('DropDownValue').addProperty('xpath', ConditionType.EQUALS, "//md-option[contains(text(), 'AVAN - Advancè')]")
WebUI.waitForElementVisible(dropdownValue, 30)
WebUI.click(dropdownValue)
```